# LINQ to match substring from another list

Tags: c#, linq

I'd like to match a list of items against another list, where a partial match is considered.

Consider the two lists, which are simiplifed to demonstrate what I'm after.  One is complete part numbers.

```
Part Number        Priority
278700-002         44
278700-003         40
278900-001         80
324100-001         20
```

A second list has a set of rules for part numbers, but this list may only contain a prefix:

```
Part Prefix      Priority Delta
278700           1
278700-002       1
3                -5
8000             2
```

I was hoping to find a LINQ expression that would enable me to find all rules for a given part.  This would mean, for example, that `278700-002` would match on both the `278700-002` rule and the `278700` rule.

I've been able to do this in what appears to be a clumsy approach, but was interested if it's possible to do this with a LINQ one-liner.

Here is a notional example of each object:

```
public class Rule
{
    public string PartPrefix;
    public int PriorityBump;
}

public class Part
{
    public string PartNumber;
    public int Priority;
}
```

And the code within the method that would implement the rules.  For simplicity sake, I'm just incrementing the priority value, but in reality I'd like a lamda within List.FindAll() where it returns a list matching rules for every Part Number.

```
    List<Part> parts;
    List<Rule> rules;

    public static void RePrioritize()
    {
        foreach (Part p in parts)
        {
            foreach (Rule r in rules)
            {
                if (r.PartPrefix.Equals(p.PartNumber.Substring(0,
                    r.PartPrefix.Length)))
                    p.Priority += r.PriorityBump;
            }
        }
    }
```

Instead of the `foreach (Rule r`, I was seeking a LINQ function like this:

```
rules.FindAll(x => x.PartPrefix.IsContainedIn(p.PartNumber));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about `rules.Where(x => p.PartNumber.StartsWith(x.PartPrefix));`

I'm not giving a larger LINQ because you specified to replace only the inner foreach (`foreach (Rule r`), and not the external foreach.

Answer (score 1):

You can try using `StartsWith` method:

```
var prefixes = parts.Select(x => x.PartNumber).ToArray();

var result = rules.Where(x => prefixes.Any(p => p.StartsWith(x.PartPrefix));
```